# what is the table name that postgres uses to log errors

Tags: postgresql, logging

I am new to Postgres and would like to know if there is a table where Postgres logs the errors if there is any. Something similar to the `Oracle` equivalent = `dba_errors`

Answer (score 2):

Errors are logged to the error log, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html). You can log to a file, the syslog daemon (on Unix) or the event log (on Windows).

There is no support for logging to a table, bbut you can load a CSV log file into a table.

Comment: Hmm. That is not what I was hoping for but thank you for the answer @Laurenz :)

Comment: What exactly were you hoping for?

Comment: I was hoping to get all the errors in the db (preferably from a simple table) and check if they are related to the schema I am interested in, then inform the admin of the db. But I will try and fetch the errors from the log file, since you mentioned that is the only way.